# WebGL warning: texImage: Alpha-premult and y-flip are deprecated for non-DOM-Element uploads

Tags: javascript, django, webgl, mapbox

So I have been trying to use Map-box to plot coordinates in my App, but when I provide the `.png` file to act as a marker, I get this following error:

> WebGL warning: texImage: Alpha-premult and y-flip are deprecated for non-DOM-Element uploads.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFNUQ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you uploading textures yourself or is it happening through mapbox?

In any case you can upload textures in 3 ways

1. raw data via typedarrays
2. from an HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, or HTMLVideoElement
3. from an ImageBitmap

Separately there are options when you upload you can set with `gl.pixelStorei`. Two options are `UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL`, set to true it flips the data vertically before uploading to the GPU. `UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL` set to true it would premultiply RGB by alpha before uploading.

It used to be that all 3 methods of uploading data respected those flags but browsers decided that method (1) and (3) should not use those flags going forward so if they're set to true you'll get the message they're deprecated.

For ImageBitmap the reason they're deprecated is that [ImageBitmap itself has those options](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) so you're supposed to use them there where they can be done asychronously. For TypedArrays, since you're 100% in control of the data it's expected you can deal with it yourself.